# How to use Glassers Master Theorem for this one

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1+t^2}{(1+a^2)t^4+2t^2+1} dt
$$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}$

I already divided by $t^2$ on both the numerator and denominator, and used substitution $x = t - \frac{1}{t}$.  It didn't work because of the coefficient $1+a^2$ in $t^2$.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried already? Some more context is always helpful for others to understand. Regardless, here's a hint: divide the numerator and denominator by $t^2$.

Comment: I already did that but I just end up into $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1+t^{-2}}{(1+a^2)t^2+2+t^{-2}} dt$ However If I use the substitution x = t - 1/t, It didn't work because of the coefficient 1+a^2 in t^2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After dividing by $t^2$, take $(1+a^2)$ outside the denominator. We get:

$$ I = \frac{1}{a^2+1} \cdot \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1+\frac{1}{t^2}}{t^2+\frac{2}{1+a^2} + \frac{1}{(1+a^2)t^2}} dt$$

Let

$$\beta = \frac{1}{1+a^2}$$

Rewriting, we get

$$ I = \beta \cdot \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1+\frac{1}{t^2}}{t^2+ 2\beta + \frac{\beta}{t^2}} dt$$

Now let

$$ 1 + \frac{1}{t^2} = \lambda_1 \cdot ( 1 + \frac{\sqrt{\beta}}{t^2}) + \lambda_2 \cdot ( 1 - \frac{\sqrt{\beta}}{t^2})$$

Now, all you have to do is find the values of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, split the integral into two separate integrals - the first one, you substitute $ x = t - \frac{\sqrt{\beta}}{t}$ and for the second one you can substitute $ x = t + \frac{\sqrt{\beta}}{t}$ and proceed.

It is easy to compute the integral after this substitution.

Comment: Ohhh Just like how $\int \sqrt{\tan(x)} dx$ solve?